# Сериализация виджетов и кода, который они реализуют

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

В Qt имеется такой интересный инструмент, как [Qt UI Tools](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtuitools-module.html), позволяющий реконструировать сериализованные виджеты.

Это может быть полезно, например, если в клиент-серверном приложении сервер будет отвечать не только за основную логику, но и влиять на формирование пользовательского интерфейса. Скажем, по причине наличия собранных в единую систему модулей, каждый из которых имеет свои диалоги настройки.

Конечно не составит труда организовать собственный протокол, чтобы описать параметры настроек этих модулей, но предположим, что это затруднительно по той причине, что процесс изменения каждой из опций диалога настроек требует организации обмена некими промежуточными данными между сервером и клиентом. От этого произвольный протокол сильно разрастается от добавлемых в него различных условий.

В связи с этим было бы очень удобно, если бы модуль сервера каким-то образом полностью описал весь виджет (набор виджетов), описал данные, которые должны содержаться в этом виджете (данные, формирующиеся в `runtime`), и наконец - код, который должен выполняться при некоторых действиях пользователя над виджетом.

Первое и второе реализуется очевидным образом. Любой виджет можно сериализовать на серверной стороне, а воспроизвести уже на клиентской. Данные времени исполнения программы, которые должны быть размещены в реконструируемом виджете, можно передать отдельно, и по неким общим правилам клиентская часть занесёт их во вновь созданный виджет.

А вот как быть с тем, к примеру, что если виджет содержит кнопку, и у одного модуля эта кнопка должна делать одно, а у другого - другое? Как передать логику выполнения так, чтобы протокол обмена данными между сервером и клиентом не начал разрастаться различными условиями?

Прошу поделиться опытом реализации обозначенного механизма, и если использовали `QUiLoader` или, быть может, `QFormBuilder`, то как передавали собственно код/логику отдельных виджетов. Вообще возникает вопрос, зачем нужен тот же `QUiLoader`, если передать виджет возможность есть, а то, что он должен делать - нет?

Возможным решением задачи я вижу использование плагинов. Плагины можно было бы передавать по сети как файлы, тут даже `QUiLoader` не потребуется. Но очень беспокоит сопутствующее разрастание проекта приложения, поскольку каждый отдельный плагин - это фактически подпроект.

Comment: Ох уж это компонетно-ориентированное программирование... Такой вопрос, логика, посылаемая сервером, может быть совсем любая, или её можно изначально иметь на клиенте частями?

Comment: Какие-то части конечно можно. Например, таблицы, у которых имеются стандартные действия, по типу добавления, изменения и удаления элементов. Но некоторые действия, совершенно выбиваются из общей схемы, и их наличие принципиально. Суть моего вопроса в том, есть ли возможность сэкономить с тем, чтобы, раз уж всё равно каждый модуль индивидуально расписывается в серверной части, то заодно туда и UI запихать и быть уверенным, что если затем потребуется вносить изменения, то всё, что нужно будет находиться в одном месте.

Comment: Могу лишь плюсануть и тоже ждать ответа... Кстати, думаю, имеет смысл указать платформу, логика ведь везде по-разному хранится.

Comment: Спасибо. Да хотя бы просто принцип, но если мой конкретный случай, то обычный десктоп, не мобильные устройства, с обычным сервером.

Comment: @alexis031182, а насколько вы готовы доверять исполняемому коду, приходящему неизвестно от кого и откуда, чтобы запускать его с правами текущего пользователя? Ну а по сути – код можно пересылать в виде обычной динамической библиотеки и подключать её прямо во время выполнения программы. Только нужно учитывать разнообразие клиентских операционных систем и версий Qt.

Comment: Такое ощущение, что это проще организовать, используя веб-решения. Т.е. клиент-сайд в браузере, на js

Comment: Что-то такое было у PyQt, можно было в редакторе генерировать xml для интерфейса, а питоновский код грузил ее. По факту там только файл указывался.

Answer (score 1):

> А вот как быть с тем, к примеру, что если виджет содержит кнопку, и у одного модуля эта кнопка должна делать одно, а у другого - другое?

**Я бы предложил подумать в следующем направлении:**

- `Qt` - позволит нам динамичеси строить любые возможные интерфейсы
- `SQL` базы - позволят нам в структурном виде хранить не только данные, но и визуальные схемы/размещения, а так же логику в виде скриптов. Писать скомпилированные плагины на C++ особого смысла не вижу, ибо для UI - быстродействие критерий второстепенный
- `Lua` - позволит, собственно, реализовать логику, подгружаемую динамически

**Небольшая приблизительная декомпозиция вопроса**

`Элемент управления`

У нас уже есть их ограниченное количество, например, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QTableView, etc ... Давайте их перечислим в БД в виде таблицы и присвоим им уникальные ID, чтобы в дальнейшем было на что ссылаться.

`Группы`

Это некоторое количество элементов управление, которые работают совместно. Тут речь не идет пока о визуализации, а лишь о том, что для определенных действий одновременное наличие этих элементов необходимо. И более того, группы должно мочь формировать не только из элементов управления, но из других групп. Здесь и далее - наверное им придется придавать все свойства "элементов управления". Разница только в совместной независимой или зависимой работе. Давайте группы и их состав зарегистрируем в базе.

`Роли`

Это особенности применения элементов управления в группе. Какие именно, определимся позже. А пока зарегистрируем все роли в базе.

`Ограничения`

Это задаваемые статически или формируемые динамически условия валидности значений, которые могут содержаться в элементах управления. Сами по себе ограничения, в отрыве от контекста, бессмысленны - они должны быть привязаны к роли/ролям. Но их тоже нужно зарегистрировать в базе.

`Состояния`

Это совокупность возможностей или невозможнойстей элементов управления выполнять действия по требуемым ролям.

`Сигналы`

Это события, которые могут генерировать элементы управления в зависимости от роли. На данные события, понятное дело, будет реакция соседних, или вышележащих элементов управления. Давайте их зарегистрируем в базе данных.

`Действия`

Это, собственно, программно реализуемые манипуляции как с элементами управления, так и с прикладными данными. Они "привязываются" к сигналам (которые, как написал выше, сами привязываются к ролям). Давайте их зарегистрируем в базе данных.

**Небольшая приблизительная композиция вопроса**

Выше перечислены основные сущности, манипулируя которыми, таки можно динамически собирать нужную нам бизнес-логику под каждый нужный нам UI. Благо все сущности в базе данных зарегистрированы, имеют уникальные идентификаторы. Остается самое сложное - зарегистрировать в базе данных непротиворечивые, неизбыточные связи, что "вяжется" с чем.

В общем, вот такое рассуждение. Я понимаю - все "по верхам", но, уверен - такой подход правильный. Другой вопрос - а нужно ли это все, важно ли?)